# mock system.getenv in spring boot test using junit without using powermockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit4, spring-boot-test

i have one class in that i'm getting the value from environment varible. for that i have to write junit test case.
**Service class**

```
@service
public class MyService{

@Autowired
MongoClient mongoClient;

public void save(){
String mongoUri= System.getenv("mongodb_url");
if(mongoUri!=null){
  List<String> databaseNames = mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().into(new ArrayList<>());
        for (String dbName : databaseNames) {
          log.info(dbname+"database name");
}
}
}
}
```

**TestClass**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
    DefaultTestService.class})
public class test {

  @Mock
  Environment environment;
  @InjectMocks
  MyService myservice;

  @Test
  public void test(){
    when(System.getenv("mongodb_url")).thenReturn("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    myservice.save();
}
}
```

**gradle dependencies**

```
 implementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
```

getting null for the environment variable. how to set environment varible to pass this testcase how to achieve this could any one please help?

Comment: Don't. Use the Spring environment abstraction and then you can pass it simply with `@TestPropertySource`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you please elaborate the statement. how to use Spring environment abstraction in this scenario

Comment: Inject the `Environment` and use that to get the property, that will eventually also check the environbment. Generally when you are calling `System.getenv` or `System.getProperty` you are doing it wrong (at least in a Spring application).

Comment: Tried this but getting same result. without setting the environment variable also this test case should pass

Comment: Please read... If you use the `Environment` you can just add an `@TestPropertySource` to set the property. It will then override any set environment property or use it if not set.

Comment: You mean like this ?? 
`
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
    DefaultTestService.class})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"mongodb_url=localhost:27017"})
public class test {

  @Mock
  Environment environment;
  @InjectMocks
  MyService myservice;
}
`

Comment: That should work, however your test is weird. Why run it with Spring Boot if you are mocking everything? Either use Spring Boot for the test, or don't. If you don't you will have to mock behavior for the `Environment`.

Comment: Yes you are right . thanks for your help. 
`public static void set(Map<String, String> newenv) throws Exception {
    Class[] classes = Collections.class.getDeclaredClasses();
    Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    for(Class cl : classes) {
        if("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap".equals(cl.getName())) {
            Field field = cl.getDeclaredField("m");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object obj = field.get(env);
            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) obj; map.clear();
 map.putAll(newenv);}}}`
the above code also helps